# Dynamically position the \closing along the senders' address

Tags: letters

In the format we were taught at school, the position of the `\closing` aligns with sender's address.
In the MWE given below: I have had to adjust the position of the `\closing` by eye by making `\setlength` specifications for `\longindentation`. Is there a way to get this done automatically?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, left=2.0cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setlength\parindent{0cm}           % Paragraph indentation


%%% Adjusting the \closing specifications:
%1. Decreases the default gap between the closing remark (Warrm regards) and the senders name.
%2. Looking to make its position align with the sender's address.
\renewcommand\closing[1]{\par\nobreak\vspace{\parskip}%
\stopbreaks%
\noindent%
\ifx\@empty\fromaddress\else%
\hspace*{\longindentation}\fi%
\parbox{\indentedwidth}{\raggedright%
\ignorespaces #1\\[\medskipamount]%
\ifx\@empty\fromsig%
\fromname%
\else \fromsig \fi\strut}%
\par}
%%%%


\signature{Ginko Mitten}
\address{21 Jump Street,\\Mink Road,\\ Uganda}

%%%% dynamic adjustment of closing position %%%
\setlength{\longindentation}{0.78\textwidth}
%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
Prof. Minao Sloan,\\
Room 45,\\
University of Computation,\\
Mexico City,\\
Mexico}

\opening{%
\begin{center}
\textbf{Subject}: Our meeting next month.
\end{center}%
Dear Prof. Sloan}

Blah Blah Blah. Quantum computing very interesting. Blah blah blah.\par

Thank you very much for your time. I hope to get in touch with you soon.

\closing{Warm regards,}


\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around the redefinition of `\closing`, otherwise `\ifx\@empty...` will *always* return false because it compares `\@` with `e`.

Now let's solve your problem: you want to measure the “from address” and the date, so you can use a `\parbox` with the same size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, left=2.0cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage{microtype}

%%% Adjusting the \closing specifications:
%1. Decreases the default gap between the closing remark (Warrm regards) and the senders name.
%2. Looking to make its position align with the sender's address.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\closing[1]{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\parskip}%
  \stopbreaks
  \ifx\@empty\fromaddress\else
    \hspace*{\fill}%
  \fi
  \sbox0{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\fromaddress\\\today\end{tabular}}%
  \parbox[t]{\wd0}{%
    \raggedright
    \ignorespaces #1\\[\medskipamount]
    \ifx\@empty\fromsig
      \fromname
    \else
      \fromsig
    \fi
    \strut
  }%
  \par
}
\makeatother
%%%%


\signature{Ginko Mitten}
\address{21 Jump Street,\\Mink Road,\\ Uganda}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
Prof. Minao Sloan,\\
Room 45,\\
University of Computation,\\
Mexico City,\\
Mexico}

\opening{%
\begin{center}
\textbf{Subject}: Our meeting next month.
\end{center}%
Dear Prof. Sloan}

Blah Blah Blah. Quantum computing very interesting. Blah blah blah.\par

Thank you very much for your time. I hope to get in touch with you soon.

\closing{Warm regards,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

(I don't find this particularly attractive, though.)

[image]